# Is it possible to make an array of objects in Ruby on Rails ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, sorting, object

I want to create a temporary array of objects in Ruby on Rails so I can save some data, and subsequently print it. I know, it sounds weird, but it will make sense in the grander scheme of what I am trying to do !

Here is my code so far:

```
  <% peopleArray = Array.new %>
  <% familyArray = Array.new %>
  <% friendsArray = Array.new %>


  <% @subject.list_people.each do |people| %>
    <% people.people_family.each do |family| %>
      <% family.find_friends.each do |friends| %>
        <% peopleArray << people %>
        <% familyArray << family %>
        <% friendsArray << friends %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Instead of pushing these entire objects into separate arrays, I would like to select one field from each of these three objects, make a new object out of this, and insert it into an array. So each object in the array will have 3 attributes, and I will then be able to sort by one.

Is this possible, given that all array in Ruby are just arrays of objects, from what I understand?

I have been playing around with this for a little while, trying to learn ROR, trying to massage the data into the format I want, and not gotten anywhere.

Each object, `people`, `family` and `friends` has an attribute I want to save.

Let's say each object has a field, "name", and I want to add that to a new object. How can I do this? Here's an attempt with psuedocode to show what I wish to achieve. Is is possible?

```
  myArray = Array.new //create array 

  <% @subject.list_people.each do |people| %>
    <% people.people_family.each do |family| %>
      <% family.find_friends.each do |friends| %>

       myObj = new Object //create object

        <% myObj.name1 = people['name'].first %>
        <% myObj.name2 = family['name'].first %>
        <% myObj.name3 = friends['name'].first %>
        <% myArray << myObj %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
 <% end %> 
    <% myArray.sort(name1) %> //Sort the list based on field name1.
```

Apologies if any of this is obvious, I have done a lot of research not been able to make much headway so I hope this post is allowed here.

Comment: Of course, but... you need either an actual class, or an OpenStruct, or even a hash. You can't magically make the base Object class know what you intend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your "Object", you may want to use a [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html) or a [`Struct`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Struct.html). But, go with a `Hash`.

```
 myArray = []

  <% @subject.list_people.each do |people| %>
    <% people.people_family.each do |family| %>
      <% family.find_friends.each do |friends| %>

       myObj = {}

        <% myObj['name1'] = people['name'].first %>
        <% myObj['name2'] = family['name'].first %>
        <% myObj['name3'] = friends['name'].first %>

        <% myArray << myObj %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %> 
  <% myArray.sort_by! { |obj| obj['name1'] } %> //Sort the list based on field name1.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was really helpful and taught me a lot about how to construct these objects :).